# How to script a reinstall (apt repo's and installed packages)

Tags: installation, scripts, automation

I need to wipe my hard drive and reinstall Ubuntu.  /home is on a separate partition, so I can back that up to a backup drive, then copy it back to the wiped drive, install ubuntu, and point it at the existing /home, [no problem](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-partplan/index.html).

However, I also want to script a reinstall of all my apt repo's and the packages I currently have installed, so I don't have to waste hours doing that manually.  Anyone know a good way to do this?

PS - At least, I'm pretty sure I have to wipe the drive.  Need to install Windows 7, and only have an HP system restore disk that formats the whole drive, and not a legit Windows 7 install disk that lets me install on a single partition.  If somebody know a way to trick the system restore disk to install only to a single partition, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to save a list of your currently installed packages

```
dpkg --get-selections > my_apps.txt
```

After you've reinstalled, this selects all of your packages

```
dpkg --set-selections < my_apps.txt
```